# Converting date string to time in millis returns negative number

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to convert a string date with the following pattern 20221231 into a Long (to get the time in millis).
I've tried many ways to do it but I always get a negative number.

My last solution is using DateUtils from apache as follow:
`return DateUtils.parseDate(dateString, DATE_FORMAT).getTime();`

with `DATE_FORMAT` equals `yyyyMMdd`
I've also tried format `YYYYMMDD`
but for some reason I always get a negative number

EX: for a string date 19330601, I get -1154566800000

Any idea ? thanks

Comment: Millis are relative to the unix epoch, 1970. 1933 is before that, thus negative. The number is correct.

Comment: It seems you are using `java.util.Date`? I strongly recommend you don’t. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @Michael It would seem to me that you can post that as an answer if you want. It very precisely and clearly explains what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

```
String dateString = "20200101";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
LocalDate timeA = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
long epoch = timeA.toEpochDay();
LocalDate timeB = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(epoch);

System.out.println("Original Time: " + timeA);
System.out.println("From epoch: " + timeB);
```

Comment: OP's code is already working, so dumping some alternative code with zero explanation of how it's better or different from what they already have is not useful.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your code is fine, but I fail to see the connection to the question.